# R: Create/assign multiple objects from function parameters to debug

Tags: r, function, performance, debugging, parameters

When trying to debug a function, I often find myself loading all the parameters one by one:

```
myfun <- function(
param1 = NULL,
param2 = "character",
param3 = a.data.frame)
```

Which is tedious since you have to drag-select the line until the comma, for each line.

i.e. select

```
param1 = NULL
```

control+enter to load param1 into the environment. Then select

```
param2 = "character"
```

control+enter to load param2 into the environment. And so forth, often for loads of parameters.

Does anyone know if there's a quicker way to do this? If you select the whole block & hit control+enter it doesn't work due to the commas.

Sometimes I'll copy the whole block, paste it immediately below, and delete the commas, but that's only if I have to keep doing this due to a tricky problem.

Thanks!

Comment: I can't visualize what you're trying to do... Could you give us an example?

Comment: Apologies - done now.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly, you can make a list with the arguments and make use of `do.call`:

```
lst <- list(
  param1 = NULL,
  param2 = "",
  param3 = data.frame()
)

foo <- function(param1, param2, param3) {} # your function here

do.call(foo, lst)
```

Comment: Thanks. So after loading all of the params into the environment, I'm then stepping through the main function, not actually running it directly, so I can debug some step within the function, or have the environment setup as it would be midway through the function, and then add/change functionality. Given that, would I need a function for `foo`, or would that line + `do.call` be enough to cause those params to be imported into the environment? Thanks.

Comment: `foo` is just an empty example function. In this case, you replace it by the function that you want to debug. If the idea is to test the function behavior according to parameter changing, you can create new lists (like `lst`) and pass them inside `do.call`.

Comment: Ah, so, my aim is to debug/code within the function (in this case `foo`) by getting a certain way through the function code with the environment as it would be were I to have run the function natively then stopped. I do wonder if I'm missing something in debugging though, if this is unusual practice, i.e. should I be able to put a breakpoint in the function script, then call the function with a second script, and thus step into the function that way? Your use of `do.call` for parameter changing is super cool though, I'll definitely use this in future, thank you!